# Sorted vector of indices from a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix

My question is more understable with an example.

Given an arbitrary vector, i.e. `[6 2 5]`, I want to get another vector whose elements are the sorted indices of the input vector: in this case, `[3 1 2]`.

Is there any MATLAB function capable of returning this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the second argument of `sort` twice

```
[~, tmp] = sort( myInput );
[~, myOutput] = sort( tmp );
```

---

Regarding running times:

```
n = 1000; 
x = unique(randi(100*n,1,n)); %// make sure all elements of x are different
tic; %// try this answer
[ii t]=sort(x);
[ii out1]=sort(t);
toc, 
tic;
out2 = sum(bsxfun(@ge, x, x.'));
toc
```

Output:

```
 Elapsed time is 0.000778 seconds.  %// this answer
 Elapsed time is 0.003835 seconds.  %// bsxfun approach
```

Answer (score 3):

If all elements of the input vector `x` are **assured to be different**, you could use [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html): for each element of `x`, count how many elements (including itself) it equals or exceeds:

```
y = sum(triu(bsxfun(@ge, x(:).', x(:))), 1);
```

If the elements of `x` are **not necessarily different**, you need an additional step to make sure comparisons are done only with previous and current elements:

```
m = bsxfun(@ge, x(:).', x(:));
y = sum(m & ~tril(m,-1).', 1);
```

Comment: As much as I LOVE `bsxfun`, in this case your solution is O(n^2) while `sort` based solution is O( n log(n) )...

Comment: @Shai Yes... Just to provide some alternative :-)